# CollectionView teasing previous and next

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

My question is a bit simple, I think, but don't see how to achieve this.

I would like to have a horizontal `UICollectionView` where I can see my previous and next cell.
I already set up a horizontal, paging-enabled `collectionView` and its flow layout.
I "just" miss this thing.

Here is a mockup of what I would like to have.

[image]

My problem is : I can't get this position : current cell centered and previous and next appearing. I  played with `- minimumInteritemSpacing` and `- sectionInset` property of my layout without success.

Comment: erm... ok, so... what's the problem again?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I've edited my post if it can help more

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? Are you using FlowLayout? Try simply setting the cell width to something less than the screen width, that should be enougn

Comment: Try to use a scroll view

Comment: had you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution?

Comment: You can take help from this great library https://github.com/KelvinJin/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout , cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the following layout:

```
import UIKit

/**
 A UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass that snaps to the nearest cell as soon as the user stops dragging.
 Respects the scrolling velocity.
 Only _Horizontal_ direction is supported.
 */
class SnapCenterLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity) }
    let parent = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)

    let itemSpace = itemSize.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
    var currentItemIdx = round(collectionView.contentOffset.x / itemSpace)

    // Skip to the next cell, if there is residual scrolling velocity left.
    // This helps to prevent glitches
    let vX = velocity.x
    if vX > 0 {
      currentItemIdx += 1
    } else if vX < 0 {
      currentItemIdx -= 1
    }

    let nearestPageOffset = currentItemIdx * itemSpace
    return CGPoint(x: nearestPageOffset,
                   y: parent.y)
  }
}
```